# Enable returning multiple arguments as completion reply at once in fish shell

Tags: autocomplete, fish, tab-completion, completion

I am working on porting Google Cloud SDK command line auto completion feature to fish shell. When I have an unambiguous reply with multiple arguments:

A) Either the command is completed with all those arguments BUT spaces gets escaped (\ ) when I specify the function call in the complete command inside ''s or ""s, like: > complete ... -a '(__fun)'

B) or if I don't do that (just: -a (__fun)), then only the first argument of the reply gets into the completion and all the other arguments "get lost"

Is it possible to reply with multiple arguments at once in fish completion?

Comment: fish tab completion only expands to a single argument. For my own information, what's a case where you would want to insert multiple arguments at once?

Comment: E.g. when you want to use 'gcloud compute ssh ' the sdk can complete it with both the instance name --zone and the zone, which is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done in a number of ways. You will have to hack it a bit, though, since as ridiculous_fish says it's not designed for this. 
Easiest would be to ship your own wrapper function that can take the escaped output and pass it on in a way that works. Not very pretty, though, and would screw with autosuggestions unless you also go back and modify the history lines.

Here's something semi-hacky/semi-elegant I would propose:
If you have looked up a "sequence" of args you'd want to complete at once, at first invocation put the trailing args as the description to the first one. Once that one has been locked in, remove all other options but the first in this "description queue", keep going through it and it will simply be a matter of quickly pressing tab-tab-tab-tab.

Completions don't have to be perfect, they're mostly a lil help on the way until you have enough history lines that autosuggestions take over, imo.

Comment: I could not figure this out. Since I am calling compete as:

Comment: complete -x -c gcloud -a '(__python_argcomplete)'

Comment: Right now I return the options inside my __python_argcomplete function with echo-ing them one-by-one. According to fish docs, I could provide a description inside the complete call with -d 'description'. But that is outside of the function call, and since I could emit multiple options inside it each potantially should have its individual description. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is how far I could get, works as you suggested w/o the descriptions: https://github.com/Doctusoft/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion Planning to add more features later

Comment: Yeah -d will put the same description for everything. For individual ones just put a tab between the completion and the description, so like comp1\tdesc1\ncomp2\tdesc2\n etc

Comment: Thanks a lot, [changes](https://github.com/Doctusoft/google-cloud-sdk-fish-completion/issues/1) implemented. I found no better way to do this correctly then echo -n <firstarg>; echo -n -e "\t"; echo <desc> which might be silly but works

Comment: No worries! No yeah that's the way to do it. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted hey :)